# MVC Razor, Srt default button on enter click, form without an input textbox

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, model-view-controller

I need to trigger submit on a form where there is no input textbox. It has a date range selection and a submit button. On changing the date and pressing on enter key it should repopulate my data.I have tried setting default button and using

```
$("#MainForm").keypress(function(e) , unfortunately both are not working.
@using (Html.BeginForm("a", "a", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "RepForm", defaultButton = "SubmitButton"}))
<button id="daterangepicker2"></button>      
<input type="submit" value="SubmitButton" class="btn-primary btn" id="SubmitButton"/>
 $(document).ready(function() {  $("#RepForm").keydown(function (e) { if (e.which == "13") { var defaultButtonId = $("#RepForm").attr("defaultbutton");  $("#" + defaultButtonId).click(); }});
```

Comment: Can you show some code or your efforts? That will be of more help to whoever is addressing your question.

Comment: please some code part you did.

Comment: "@using (Html.BeginForm("a", "a", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "RepForm", defaultButton = "SubmitButton"}))
<button id="daterangepicker2"> </button>      
<input type="submit" value="SubmitButton" class="btn-primary btn" id="SubmitButton" />
---------------------------------------
 $(document).ready(function() {  $("#RepForm").keydown(function (e) { if (e.which == "13") { var defaultButtonId = $("#RepForm").attr("defaultbutton");  $("#" + defaultButtonId).click(); }});"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to perform form submit on changing date, you can use below code.

```
$('#YourDateControl').change(function()
{
      $('#MainForm').trigger('submit');
});
```

It may helps you, if it is your requirement.